# Showing that $f(x) = x^3$ is injective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

This is my attempt. Is it right? Is there a simpler way? Is there a way which relies on less background knowledge?

---

A function is injective iff $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$. This is equivalent to $x \not = y \implies f(x) \not = f(y)$. We will prove this latter statement by contradiction:

Suppose there are two numbers $x$, $x+a$ with $a >0$ and $x \not = x+a$ but $x^3 = (x+a)^3$. Expanding the RHS, subtracting $x^3$, and dividing both sides by $a>0$ yields $0 = 3x^2 + 3xa + a^2$. Taking this last equation as a quadratic in $x$, it has a real solution iff the discriminant is non-negative. But the discriminant is $9a^2 - 12a^2 = -3a^2$, so there are no real $x$ which satisfy $x^3 = (x+a)^3$.

Comment: Looks perfect to me.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Could just cube root it directly, getting cubic roots of unity and then analyse each case?

Comment: @TCiur the statement that a "cube root function" $g(x)$ exists such that $g(x^3) = x$ for all $x$ seems obviously stronger than the statement that the $f(x) = x^3$ is injective.

Comment: This proof works if $a\neq 0$, not simply if $a>0$.

Comment: The only real cube root of unity is 1 so pretty sure the result follows, with some extra work.

Comment: @TCiur It does, with a **lot** of extra work (relative to the subject matter level) including topics probably not covered by the op in his/her class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might say $a\ne 0$ instead of $a>0$ just for a nice symmetry, but that's purely aesthetic, your answer is a good one. An alternative is let $x\ne y$ and consider

> $$x^3-y^3 = (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$$

Then by the AM-GM inequality, $x^2+y^2 > 2|xy|>|xy|$--strict because $x\ne y$--so the only way for this difference to be $0$ is if $x=y$.

Comment: I chose $a>0$ when I started the proof because I thought I might have to split it into $2$ cases otherwise, but I see now that it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Ovi I figured something like that was the case:  your answer was already so well done I thought you'd like feedback on how to make it immaculate. :)

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $$x^3=y^3$$ then $$(x-y)(y^2+xy+x^2)=0$$ so either $x=y$ or $$x^2+xy+y^2=\left(x+\frac y2\right)^2+\frac {3y^2}4=0$$

But this is strictly non-negative and is zero only if $x=y=0$

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a way which relies on less background knowledge?*

Yes, there is (probably the most elementary one, which is based essentially in the monotonicity of multiplication):

> **Claim 1.** If $x\neq 0$, $y\neq 0$ and $x^3=y^3$ then $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

*Proof:* Assume that $x^3=y^3$ with $x>0$ and $y<0$. Then
$$0<x^3=y^3=(-1)^3(-y)^3<0,$$
which is a contradiction. $\square$

> **Claim 2:** $f(x)=x^3$ is injective.

*Proof:* Note that $x^3=xxx\neq 0$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $0^3=0$. So, if $f(x)=x^3$ is not injective then there exist two real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that:

- $x\neq 0$, $y\neq0$
- $x\neq y$
- $x^3=y^3$

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $x<y$. It follows from Claim 1 that $0<x<y$ or $0>y>x$. Thus
$$x^3=xxx<yyy=y^3$$
which is a contradiction. $\square$

**Remark.** Note that this proof relies only in the following elementary facts:

- $a<b \text{ and }c>0\quad \Longrightarrow \quad ac<bc$
- $a<b \text{ and }c<0\quad \Longrightarrow \quad ac>bc$
- $ab=0\quad \Longrightarrow \quad a=0\text{ or }b=0$
- $-a=(-1)a\text{ and } -(-a)=a$
- $ab=ba$
- $0^2=0$
- $(-1)^2=1$
- $-1<0$